# How to set and access environment variables in python file for Streamlit app?

Tags: python, streamlit

How do you properly set secret keys or environment variables when you deploy your files to github to be deploy to Streamlit app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streamlit has an option in the advanced settings before you deploy your application to store your secret keys and environment variables

[image]

And inside your app, you can just query the variables as below:

```
import streamlit as st

# Everything is accessible via the st.secrets dict:

st.write("DB username:", st.secrets["db_username"])
st.write("DB password:", st.secrets["db_password"])
st.write("My cool secrets:", st.secrets["my_cool_secrets"]["things_i_like"])

# And the root-level secrets are also accessible as environment variables:

import os

st.write(
    "Has environment variables been set:",
    os.environ["db_username"] == st.secrets["db_username"],
)
```

Source: https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/connect-to-data-sources/secrets-management